# convert gdb to csv in batches

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, csv, file-geodatabase

I have 88 gdb files on Arcmap that I need to export to csv format. Is it possible to do this in batches? maybe, without using the python window

Comment: yes but why going to a flat file? - this a GIS site csv to geodatabase would make sense.

Comment: I am going between GIS and another software, so I need to have a csv format, so it's readable in both.

Comment: Would you be willing to use Python?

Comment: I have never used it before, but if worst came to worst, I would try it out!

Comment: File geodatabase (.gdb directories) is a container, not a dataset.  There could be up to two billion tables in each of those geodatabases, which increases your problem complexity by an order of magnitude.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate post of multiple questions that have already been answered. Some example are [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/what-arcgis-geoprocessing-tools-support-exporting-tabular-data-to-csv/136659#136659), [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151170/export-feature-classes-in-geodatabase-to-csvs), [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146835/export-attribute-table-values-to-csv). You can download and use this tool by ESRI Team Python [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431).

Comment: In fact, [Table to Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) will export to a .csv according to the help doc, and you can right-click and run in "Batch" in ArcCatalog or ArcMap or w/e.

Comment: Although a quick try at using Table to Table proves you can't export to CSV as the output , only read CSV as input. So someone at ESRI should update that help doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution to this referenced using a python script to run this bulk conversion:

[Conversion Solution Using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93303/bulk-convert-dbf-to-csv-in-a-folder-arcgis-10-1-using-python)

For the most part this looks outlined fairly well, and for any bulk processes (which it seems like you are doing a lot of bulk processes with bouncing between GIS and other software) python is very useful. I would look into this any try to give it a go. Also if you want to learn more about python and how it can help you, check out the following sites:

[Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python)

[Python For Beginners](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

[ArcPy Cafe](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/)

There are countless other resources out there, and the more you familiarize yourself to multiple options, the better your chances are to finding a best fit solution.

I hope that those references help you.